# Which template build method is better

Tags: php, html, templates

I found on the internet a way of building a website with templates:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']))
{ 
if($_REQUEST['page'] !="")
if(file_exists("pages/".$_REQUEST['page'].".html"))
$page_content = file_get_contents("pages/".$_REQUEST['page'].".html");
else
if (file_exists($_REQUEST['page'].".html"))
$page_content = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['page'].".html");
else
echo "<center>Page:".$_REQUEST['page']." does not exist! Please check the url and try again!</center>"; 
}
else
$page_content = file_get_contents("pages/main.html");
$page_content = str_replace("!!HEADER!!", file_get_contents("design/header.html"),$page_content);
$page_content = str_replace("!!LEFT_COLUMN!!", file_get_contents("design/left_column.html"),$page_content);
$page_content = str_replace("!!RIGHT_COLUMN!!", file_get_contents("design/right_column.html"),$page_content);
$page_content = str_replace("!!FOOTER!!", file_get_contents("design/footer.html"),$page_content); 
$page_content = str_replace("!!COMMON_TAGS!!", file_get_contents("design/common_tags.html"),$page_content);

echo $page_content;
```

To me it looks alright,but a little bit complicated for its purpose.
I use something like this:

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST["page"])) $page=$_REQUEST["page"];
 else $page="main.php";
 include 'header.php';
 echo "<div id=container>";
 echo " <div id=head>";
 include 'head.php';
 echo " </div>";
 echo " <div id=menu-container>";
include 'menu.php';
 echo " </div>";
 echo " <div id=main>";
 include $page;
 echo " </div>";
 echo "</div>";
 include 'footer.php';
```

Is there a reason for using the first method above the second ?

Comment: Yes and they should be easily found if you search something like _"why use templates"_

Comment: **Never** open files or output text using unsafe data provided by the client. Try to add `?page=<script>alert("Security!");</script>` to your URL.

Comment: @kingkero, i know the benefits of using templates,both ways are template build methods.

Comment: @PetruLebada Ok, sorry that I misunderstood. So is the question then if you should variables or include directly?

Comment: @kingkero no,the first method,opens the files , and put the content in the index with file_get_content,while the second method includes the files.In font,both ways are similar,that's why i m looking for an opinion on why,when to use which one.

Comment: @PetruLebada Then in my opinion both are not very good template engines. Motivation for the first may be that you can store the `!!..!!` stuff somewhere and use it from within all your files whereas the second attempt is quite fixed, or you need to edit the PHP but having templates is the reason you should not need to do it. Nevertheless, this is "primarily opinion based" in my opinion and hence not a good fit for SO. Just use the method you feel more comfortable with / fits your needs better